# How to retrieve the targeted substring, if the number of characters can vary?

Tags: regex

I want to retrieve from input similar to the following: `code="XY85XXXX"`, the substring between `""`.
In case of a fixed number of 8 characters I can retrieve the value with `(?<=code=").{8}`.
But the targeted substring length varies, 7 or 9, or somewhere in the range between 3 and 11 (as in the examples below) and that is what I need to also handle.
Input can for example be `code="XY85XXXX765"` or `code="123"`.

How must I adjust the regex to achieve that flexibility?

Comment: It would be nice to provide some real examples because your question unfortunately isn't that clear as expected.

Comment: If I understand correctly then `(?<=code=")(?:.{3}|.{8}|.{11})(?=")`

Comment: I did my best with making the question more readable. Seeing the comment by @MonkeyZeus I now realise that my assumption of a range might be wrong. In case you really mean only a few specific possible lengths please [edit] to correct my misunderstanding in your question and please accept my apology.

Comment: Please specify what result you expect for `code="ABC123"n"X"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookbehind to 'anchor' your matches to the fixed part `(?<=code=")` and a negative character class allowing any character but `"` occurring one or more times:

```
(?<=code=")[^"]+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead and lookbehind both searching for quotes:

```
(?<=").*(?=")
```

```js
let rx = /(?<=").*(?=")/;
let extract = (txt) => console.log(txt.match(rx)[0]);

extract('code="XY85XXXX"');
extract('code="Y85XXXX"');
extract('code="ZXY85XXXXZ"');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've copied the solution ( (?<=code=")[^"]+) in this tool https://regex101.com/ for PHP.
Ok, I get my result but when I select in the tool .NET I have no result.
What should/must be changed?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please don't give details to you question as answere. Instead edit your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.